# Java bean validation with optional fields and groups

Tags: java, validation

I have some fields which I want to be validated only for certain validation groups. Also I want these field to be optional, meaning that they can contain null, but otherwise they should have valid value.

example:

```
class Test{
    @CustomValidation1
    private String alwaysValidatedField;

    @CustomValidation2(groups = A.class)
    private String mandatoryFieldForGroupA;
    
    @CustomValidation2(groups = {B.class, C.class})
    private String optionalFieldForGroupB_C;
    
    interface A{}
    interface B{}
    interface C{}
}
```

Is there any way other than creating additional custom validations that do the same but allows null values?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but can't you just add a `boolean allowNull` attribute to the validation annotation and implement it? Or perhaps make optional fields `Optional<String>`, which also requires implementation, but more strongly telegraphs that it is optional (I have done this and it worked very well).